# Insert listener

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

There are a postgres notifications for CRUD-events for tables.

Is there a similar way for handle events from 'Slick.table.CRUD' operations?

For example:

```
val table = TableQuery[Users]
table.insert(User("name1", "passwd1")) // handle this event
```

Of course I can implement own Observer pattern. But it would be nice if there were such a possibility in Slick.